# what is the difference between load() and ajax type GET?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Hi,

I am developing a web chat with pure html and jquery but I came across this question when it comes to loading the new posts on real time. Seems like I can do it by using ajax like this.

```
       $.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         url: "load.php",
         cache: false,
         data: { roomid : 1 },
         success: function (html) {
           $("#container").html(html);
```

or I can simply use load() like this

```
$("#container").load("load.php?roomid=1");
```

I really love the simplicity if the load() method but I wonder if there is a downside or some reason why I should use ajax instead. What is the difference between both in this case?

Thank you.

Comment: load() is a wrapper for $.ajax so essentially the two are the same. The only real drawback to load is no network error handling is exposed

Comment: How about reading the docs? https://api.jquery.com/load ;) If `.load()`, which is a shorthand for `.ajax()`, works for you just go for it. If it (at some point) stops to fit for your use case, refactor your code.

Comment: load() is a wrapper? Seems like the other way around. My main concern is CPU load issues. I want my site to be as light as possible.